# Cocoapods install error- Unable to find a specification for pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am trying to **install two pods to my Xcode project** from terminal. I initially had installed a pod called `PRAugmentedReality`, and it worked fine. Then I tried adding the pod `BFTransmitter`, and started getting the following error message:

`[!] Unable to find a specification for 'PRAugmentedReality'`

**If I remove the PRAugmentedReality pod and install with just BFTransmitter, it also works fine. So basically I am able to install either on their own, but not together.**

My podfile looks like this:

```
#source for BFTransmitter
source 'https://bitbucket.org/bridgefy/bridgefypods.git'

target 'FWF' do

    pod 'BFTransmitter'
    pod 'PRAugmentedReality'

    target 'FWFTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

end
```

I have tried `repo remove master` `pod setup` and then `pod install`, still no luck.

Comment: Did you tried Cleaning your project and relaunching it? window+Shift+K clean project then close it open Workspace again and try. such error occur sometimes due to installing pods again and after launching it just build it and see if error still Exist and secondly remove both pods and install both together and check

Comment: @iOSGeek still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add source to install both pods together check my podFile and add sourced before your target as I did

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://bitbucket.org/bridgefy/bridgefypods.git'

target 'pod' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

pod 'BFTransmitter'
pod 'PRAugmentedReality'

  # Pods for pod

end
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out with this one

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem in my project.
When I was editing pod file, I changed `pod 'SCSoftKycSolutionSdkSource'` to `pod   'MyprojectName'`.

I fixed the below, issue fixed.

```
pod 'SCSoftKycSolutionSdkSource'
```

[image]